# How to solve DataSet Table with error mark in my each column?

Tags: c#, dataset

I am debugging this error on my dataset table.I dunno what error is called.I am calling a stored procedure then this error is displayed. When I run in MS SQL, it is showing fine. But when I debug in C#, the 1st table is showing fine but 2nd table is showing error mark in all my data columns (except the FieldName and I have 2 tables ).

here is my code for calling stored procedure:

```
       MySqlConn _sqlConn = new MySqlConn(Config.ConnStrO(mth));
       DataSet ds = _sqlConn.ExecSProcDS("StoreProcName", out result,UserName, dFrom, dTo);
        return ds;  //mouse over ds and view dataset visualizer the table all data got error mark
```

[**here is my error image Link !!!!**](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/attachment.php?attachmentid=21184&d=1307088966)

Comment: You will have to give us more info than this, like example data that is returned in table2 for instance, and where do you see the error, when you do a quickwatch on the table? Also, is there any error text available?

Comment: i would like to show you the image if i can....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a problem with the debugger sometimes when displaying more than one table in a dataset. see here.

The quickest solution it seems to be is instead of doing a quick watch over the whole dataset, do a quick watch on the table itself.

Have a look at the workaround on this [page](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/362994/dataset-visualizer-debugger-busy-cant-get-value-error) for an alternative method as well